# Setting individual color for each part of Box Plot in Highchart

Tags: css, highcharts

I would like to have top of the box and bottom of the box in different colors, and also top of the whisker and bottoom of the whisker in different color for each box (region).
But all of the lines in the box are in the same color (red) and top and bottom of the whisker are in the same color (green)

Live demo with steps to reproduce

```js
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'All Patients'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Asia Pacific', 'Europe', 'Latin America', 'North America', 'SWAC'],
            title: {
                text: '      '
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Annual Center Volume 2016'
            },
            tickInterval: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 75
            //plotLines: [{
            //    value: 932,
            //    color: 'red',
            //    width: 1,
            //    label: {
            //        text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
            //        align: 'center',
            //        style: {
            //            color: 'gray'
            //        }
            //    }
            //}]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            boxplot: {
                fillColor: '#F0F0E0',
                lineWidth: 2,
                upperQuartileColor: 'green',
                lowerQuartileColor: 'green',
                medianColor: '#0C5DA5',
                medianWidth: 3,
                stemColor: '#A63400',
                stemDashStyle: 'solid',
                stemWidth: 1,
                whiskerColor: '#3D9200',
                whiskerLength: '20%',
                whiskerWidth: 3                 
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Region Runs',
            showInLegend: false,
            color: 'red',
            data: [
                [2, 4, 18, 43, 53],
                [5, 9, 16.5, 32, 52],
                [1, 3, 6, 11.5, 21],
                [3, 9, 20, 38, 73],
                [1, 2, 8, 16, 20]
            ],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
            }
        },
        {
            name: '75th Percentile',
            type: 'line', 
            color: 'red',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            
        },
        {
            name: 'Median',
            type: 'line',
            color:'#0C5DA5',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            
        },
        {
            name: '25th Percentile',
            type: 'line', 
            color: 'red',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            
        },
        {
            name: '90th percentile',
            type: 'line',
            color: '#3D9200',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            
        },{
            name: '10th percentile',
            type: 'line',
            color: '#3D9200',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            
        }
        ]

    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

Box Plot Charts -->
  <div id="pdfContentHolder" style="margin:auto; width: 720px; height: 800px;">
       <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto" >
                
       </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hew8nq5u/

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: *"But all of the lines in the box are in the same color (red) and top and bottom of the whisker are in the same color (green)"* Correct. Highcharts does not have separate properties for these elements. Feature requests can be added here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general

Comment: So its like that... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not sure what else you're expecting. The feature doesn't exist. There is no clear-cut work around (aside from code it/render it yourself). You didn't actually ask a question anywhere in your post :) (and if the question is "how?", the answer is "¯\_(ツ)_/¯"). And Stack Overflow is not a feature request tool. :)  So...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks for advice sir, im new here and il keep that in mind next time i ask something. Btw i manage to do something here with appending element using jquery. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

**Currently it's not possible** in Highcharts to have box bottom and top in different colors. Same with top and bottom whiskers. Here is an explanation and enhancement proposition from **github issue** (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6796):

> Currently each box is a single SVG shape and a border is applied by
>   stroke parameter which cannot be "separated" for smaller edges. As a
>   result, you can apply only single color.
>
> Your goal requires a rebuild core of boxplot, so we cannot threat it
>   as a bug, but feature request.